# Atiyah-MacDonald help with exercise 5.10

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is an exercise from Atiyah-MacDonald, if someone can give an idea on how to prove that $a)\Rightarrow b)$:

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ a ring homomorphism.

a) $f^{*}:\operatorname{Spec}(B)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is an open mapping;

b) $f$ has the going-down property.

Comment: This problem does seem quite difficult. As a person self-studying from Atiyah & Macdonald's text, I would love to see a complete solution to this. (And I am secretly hoping that experts in this field like @Georges will someday answer this question).

Answer (score 6):

The solution is at the end of the exercise. You will need exercise 3.26 of the same book.

I copy-paste the solution (unless you have any question about it).

> To prove $(a) \Rightarrow (c)$ [recall that : $(c)$ $\operatorname{Spec}(B_q) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A_p)$ is surjective for all $q$ and $p:=f^*(q)$], observe that $B_q$ is the direct limit of $B_t$ where $t \in B-q$; hence, by Chapter 3, Exercise 26, we have $f^*(\operatorname{Spec}(B_q)) = \bigcap_t f^*(\operatorname{Spec}(B_t))$. Since $\operatorname{Spec}(B_t)$ is an open neighborhood of $q$ in $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$, and since $f^*$ is open, it follows that $f^*(\operatorname{Spec}(B_t))$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ in $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and therefore contains $\operatorname{Spec}(A_{p})$.

**EDIT:** here is a direct self-contained proof (which is the above one but detailed and shortened). Let $q$ be an ideal of $B$ and $p' \subset A$ an ideal included in $p:= f^*(q)$. Recall that the set of primes of $B$ included in $q$ and sent to $p'$ is $\operatorname{Spec} B_q \otimes_A \operatorname{Frac}(A/p')$. So we have to show that the ring
$$ B_q \otimes_A \operatorname{Frac}(A/p') = \varinjlim_{t \notin q} (B_t \otimes_A \operatorname{Frac}(A/p'))$$
is not zero, which is equivalent to prove that $B_t \otimes_A \operatorname{Frac}(A/p') \neq 0$ for all $t$ (cf. Exercises 2.20 and 2.21 of the book).

For $t \notin q$, $\operatorname{Spec} B_t$ is an open neighborhood of $q$, hence by $(a)$, $f^*(\operatorname{Spec} B_t)$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ so contains $p'$. Whence $\operatorname{Spec} B_t \otimes_A \operatorname{Frac}(A/p') \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: for me $(b) \Leftrightarrow (c)$ is obvious since $Spec(A_p)$ is set of ideals contained in $p$. Am I wrong ? Do you think one can prove the statement in a fondamentally different way ?

Comment: Dear user: no, you are perfectly right. I have deleted my unfair comment. (And I don't know if there is a more direct proof.)

Comment: Dear user10676, your direct solution in the edit seems to me quite correct: bravo and +1. It is however a bit hard to read because you changed the meaning of some letters: would you be so kind as to change your notation and make it compatible with the solution you copy-pasted? Apart from that I strongly encourage you to post under your real name: it is a pity that a mathematician of your expertise in commutative algebra should  only be known under a (very forgettable!) pseudonym.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, I learned a lot - thanks.  (but maybe it's clearer to write $\operatorname{Spec} (B_q \otimes _A \operatorname{Frac}(A/p') )$...)

Comment: FWIW, we can avoid the direct limit argument by using Exercises 3.21(i) and 3.22.